# PySide: hiding a dialog breaks the dialog.exec_()

Tags: python, dialog, pyside

In my project I have to show people a dialog which can accept or open another dialog.
I start the dialog by the usage of `dialog.exec_()` which also should make it possible to catch the `QtGui.QDialog.Accepted` and do some nice things after it.

While the first dialog opens the second dialog I try to hide the first dialog with `self.hide()` and I show it again with `self.show()` when the second dialog receives a `QtGui.QDialog.Accepted`.
This works fine, but after this the accept button of the first window does not return anything like `QtGui.QDialog.Accepted`

The thing is that it works fine until the usage of `self.hide()` and `self.show()` while opening the second window. Leaving the hiding option out makes it work without flaws.

How can I hide and show the dialog without breaking the `dialog.exec_()` which I need to know when the window gets accepted?

Comment: First, are you calling `second_dialog.exec_()` from the first dialog's code, or doing something different? More generally, can you show your (stripped-down) code, instead of making us guess?

Comment: Meanwhile, I'm not sure what you're trying to do is appropriate for modal dialogs. Hiding a modal dialog is very odd. (With the classic-Mac Toolbox API, which is where modal dialogs originally came from, doing this would crash the computer, which implies that Tog never even imagined anyone would want to try it…) Why not just pop up the second modal in front of the first, or change it into a sequence of modals instead of a stack of them? (Or, best of all, rethink your design so you don't need multiple modals…)

Answer (score 0):

Abarnert's answer made me think again about my dialog designs. First I tried it again with non-modal dialogs, but this was not consistent.

Finally I made a sequence of modal dialogs which works really great! I first start the first dialog, when its accepted it continues, however when its rejected another dialog comes up which only can get accepted. After you accept the second dialog the first dialog is executed again.

By using a while loop you can easily manage this:

```
    self.notification = firstDialog(self) #custom dialog class
    self.notification2 = secondDialog(self) #second custom dialog class

    while True:
        self.notification.show()
        if self.notification.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted: 
            break
        else: #in case of rejection (the only other option in this dialog)
            self.notification2.show()
            if self.notification2.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
                continue

    self.startFunction() #start what should happen after people accept the dialog
```